# Type mismatch involving three types that must be identical

Tags: idris

This compiles:

```
data ThreeEq : a -> b -> c -> Type where
    Same3 : (x : a)  -> ThreeEq x x x

allSameS : (x, y, z : Nat) -> ThreeEq x y z -> ThreeEq (S x) (S y) (S z)
allSameS k k k (Same3 k) = Same3 (S k)
```

But with one small change to `Same3`, it no longer compiles. Can anyone explain **why?**

```
data ThreeEq : a -> b -> c -> Type where
    Same3 : x -> ThreeEq x x x

allSameS : (x, y, z : Nat) -> ThreeEq x y z -> ThreeEq (S x) (S y) (S z)
allSameS k k k (Same3 k) = Same3 (S k)
```

Here's the error message:

```
- + Errors (1)
 `-- Amy2.idr line 5 col 0:
     When checking left hand side of allSameS:
     When checking an application of Main.allSameS:
             Type mismatch between
                     ThreeEq x x x (Type of Same3 _)
             and
                     ThreeEq k y z (Expected type)

             Specifically:
                     Type mismatch between
                             Type
                     and
                             Nat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the difference

```
data ThreeEq : a -> b -> c -> Type where
    Same3 : (x : a)  -> ThreeEq x x x
             ^   ^
             |   |
             |    Type
             Value
```

Here, `Same3 Z` builds a value of type `Three Z Z Z`.

```
data ThreeEq : a -> b -> c -> Type where
    Same3 : x -> ThreeEq x x x
            ^
            |
            Type
```

And now, `Same3 Z` builds a value of type `Three Nat Nat Nat`.